# Can web flash player publish RTMP Stream with H.264 + AAC?

Tags: actionscript-3, rtmp, flash

recently in the development of a web program which use flash player to publish RTMP stream, The problem is that the audio data is not AAC format,  are there any way to publish AAC format audio with web flash player?

Comment: what code do you use to publish the stream?

Comment: @gerrykok Flash Player can not encode audio using AAC, for that you should use a sever-side solution.

Comment: @www0z0k   NetStream.publish() .

Comment: @akmozo thank you for your reply. you're right , flash player can not do this.